# Are incrementers / decrementers (var++, var--) etc thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic

Inspired by this question: [In Complexity Analysis why is ++ considered to be 2 operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443423/in-complexity-analysis-why-is-considered-to-be-2-operations)

Take the following psuedo code:

```
class test
{
   int _counter;
   void Increment()
   {
     _counter++;
   } 
}
```

Would this be considered thread safe on an x86 architechure? Further more are the Inc / Dec assembly instructions thread safe?

Comment: jit compiler? of which platform?

Comment: Are we talking Java or C# or something else?

Comment: This question is definitely not language-agnostic! It depends a lot on which language and/or platform you're using!

Comment: Sorry I mean to leave the jit part of the question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num)

Comment: @PeterCordes similar but not identical. The other question is targeting C++. Not to mention this question/answer is a lot simpler

Comment: I understand the operator is not atomic and thus safe but can data race on it lead to "crazy" values? I.e. what if starting with i=100 and we have one writer and one reader that might data race on i++. I.e. the writer will increment and the reader will try to read somewhere within the increment assembly code block. Is there any other possible outcome for reader other than i=100 or i>100? I mean is there any case where the reader can get for example i<100? If not can we say that this -despite the data race- is eventually consistent?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, incrementing is not thread-safe. Neither are the `INC` and `DEC` instructions. They all require a load and a store, and a thread running on another CPU could do its own load or store on the same memory location interleaved between those operations.

Some languages have built-in support for thread synchronization, but it's usually something you have to ask for, not something you get automatically on every variable. Those that don't have built-in support usually have access to a library that provides similar functionality.

Answer (score 15):

In a word, no.

You can use something like `InterlockedIncrement()` depending on your platform.  On .NET you can use the `Interlocked` class methods (`Interlocked.Increment()` for example).

A [Rob Kennedy mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443500/are-incrementers-decrementers-var-var-etc-thread-safe#443530), even if the operation is implemented in terms of a single `INC` instruction, as far as the memory is concerned a read/increment/write set of steps is performed. There is the opportunity on a multi-processor system for corruption.

There's also the `volatile` issue, which would be a necessary part of making the operation thread-safe - however, marking the variable `volatile` is not sufficient to make it thread-safe.  Use the interlocked support the platform provides.

This is true in general, and on x86/x64 platforms certainly.