# Best practice to implement fixed byte serial protocol in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, protocols

I have a device connected via serial interface to a BeagleBone computer. I communicates in a simple binary format like

```
|MessagID (1 Byte) | Data (n Bytes) | checksum (2 bytes) |
```

The message length is fixed for each command, meaning that it is known how many bytes to read after the First byte of a command was received. After some initial setup communication it sends packets of data every 20 ms.

My approach would be to use either termios or something like serial lib and then start a loop doing like that (a:

```
while(keepRunning)
{
    char* buffer[256];
    serial.read(buffer, 1)
    switch(buffer[0])
        {
        case COMMAND1:
            serial.read(&buffer[1], sizeof(MessageHello)+2); //Read data + checksum
            if (calculateChecksum(buffer, sizeof(MessageHello)+3) )
            {
                extractDatafromCommand(buffer);
            }
            else
            {
                doSomeErrorHandling(buffer[0]);
            }
            break;
        case COMMAND2:
            serial.read(&buffer[1], sizeof(MessageFoo)+2);
            [...]
    }
}
```

extractDatafromCommand would then create some structs like:

```
struct MessageHello
{
    char name[20];
    int version;
}
```

Put everything in an own read thread and signal the availability of a new packet to other parts of the program using a semaphore (or a simple flag).

Is this a viable solution or are there better improvements to do (I assume so)?

Maybe make a abstract class Message and derive the other messages?

Comment: you can add a command that exits the while loop, which might be useful in some cases

Comment: I think having that read thread is a good idea.  Best not to block on the commands.  Some error recovery mechanism would also be useful.

Comment: @Taylor Flores: In the main thread loop I test for a flag which can be set. The commands come from a device I cannot change. 
I edited the test statement of the while loop.

Comment: You might define a struct for each message and then use sizeof() instead of the hard coded constants.

Comment: @PeterL.: Could you clarify what you mean with not block on commands?
My plan was to read from the serial line with blocking, thus I can wait until the full command has arrived.
Error handling is a good remark. I will add a short comment in the question.

Comment: @the_summer I meant I agree with the idea of having a dedicated thread to loop and receive/decode commands and dispatch them off to other threads than to invoke the commands directly, which might block on command completion.

Comment: @brianbeuning: Good idea. I added it in the example.

Comment: Your program seems to assume that the first byte received is the first byte of the message frame.  And this frame synchronization will persist as it reads messages.  All this breaks if a serial char is ever lost.  Finding and then maintaining message framing is crucial for a robust serial comm protocol.  A message ID and 2 checksum bytes may be a challenge for finding a variable-length message frame.  You may need to add a fixed-value sync byte to simplify the hunt for the start of the message frame.

Comment: What do you mean by *"fixed byte"* (as in your title)?

Comment: @sawdust: _fixed byte_ in the sense that after the messageId is received, the length of the message is determined.
I see your point with coming out of sync. I cannot change the protocol itself. But seeing that the id-byte is between 0xC1 and 0xEA I can check for a byte in this range to find a beginning after lost sync. If a few packages are lost it does not hurt and it should back on track eventually then.

Comment: *"Fixed byte"* is misleading.  You have **variable** length messages.  That the length is derived/deduced from the messageID rather than explicitly stored within the message is just a minor detail.  Searching for the start of the message frame is simply harder for variable-length messages compared to fixed-length messages.  If your USART has a **"receiver timeout"** feature, then you might be able to use that timer to help detect individual message frames (i.e. the 20ms between messages).  But detecting time gaps between messages has to be done by HW, not software.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends. The two major ways would be threaded (like you mentioned) and evented.

Threaded code is tricky because you can easily introduce race conditions. Code that you tested a million times could occasionally stumble and do the wrong thing after working for days or weeks or years. It's hard to 'prove' that things will always behave correctly. Seemingly trivial things like "i++" suddenly become leaky abstractions. (See [why is i++ not thread safe on a single core machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052768/why-is-i-not-thread-safe-on-a-single-core-machine) )

The other alternative is evented programming. Basically, you have a main loop that does a select() on all your file handles. Anything that is ready gets looked at, and you try to read/write as many bytes as you can without blocking. (pass O_NONBLOCK). There are two tricky parts: 1) you must never do long calculations without having a way to yield back to the main loop, and 2) you must never do a blocking operation (where the kernel stops your process waiting for a read or write).

In practice, most programs don't have long computations and it's easier to audit a small amount of your code for blocking calls than for races. (Although doing DNS without blocking is trickier than it should be.)

The upside of evented code is that there's no need for locking (no other threads to worry about) and it wastes less memory (in the general case where you're creating lots of threads.)

Most likely, you want to use a serial lib. termios processing is just overhead and a chance for stray bytes to do bad things.

Comment: Thank you for the overview. What I didn't write in the question, this communication interface will be part of a project where there are already different threads. Therefore the event loop is not an option this time, but I will keep it in mind.