# C# thread-safety on increment/decrement operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I was trying to investigate a simple piece of code with two threads accessing a shared integer variable, one incrementing and the other decrementing it:

```
static int n = 0;
static void Main()
{
    var up = new Task(() =>
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 400000; j++)
           ++n;
    });

    up.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 400000; i++)
        --n;
    up.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine(n);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I've read a number of times that C# increment/decrement operations are not thread-safe and should be replaced with Interlocked.Increment and Decrement methods. That indeed works however I when I try to set a breakpoint and check the disassembly window, it looks as if the ++ and -- operators are atomic, their assembly equivalents are

```
inc dword ptr ds:[29A0C9Ch]
```

and

```
dec dword ptr ds:[29A0C9Ch]
```

respectively.
So why is it then that the code above sometimes outputs a non-zero value?

Answer (score 2):

Because they are not atomic to start with: [How come INC instruction of x86 is not atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109679/how-come-inc-instruction-of-x86-is-not-atomic)

Interlocked synchronizes the caches on top and makes sure no interruption happens.

[why is i++ not thread safe on a single core machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052768/why-is-i-not-thread-safe-on-a-single-core-machine)

has some more details.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly explains the issue. Didn't think about atomicity of assembly instructions.

Answer (score 1):

> So why is it then that the code above sometimes outputs a non-zero value?

Because [`inc` and `dec` are not atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109679/how-come-inc-instruction-of-x86-is-not-atomic). The processor will translate these into a lower-level instructions (e.g., `inc` => read + add + store)